# Large XML file blowing up memory, how can I reduce?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xpath

I have a 200MB file that I need to cycle through and retrieve all unique xpaths. With this kind of setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<invoice>
    <id>123</id>
    <newRa elem="0">
        <createD>20150519</createD>
        <modD>12345</modD>
    </newRa>
    <total>123.99</total>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <id>456</id>
    <newRa elem="0">
        <createD>20150518</createD>
        <modD>12345</modD>
    </newRa>
    <total>456.99</total>
</invoice>
<invoice>
    <id>789</id>
    <newRa elem="0">
        <createD>20150517</createD>
        <modD>12345</modD>
    </newRa>
    <total>789.99</total>
</invoice>
```

I want to run through each invoice once, get a list of unique xpaths, and store them in stringcollection.

As I cycle through all the invoice elements, I want to add to the stringcollection ONLY when encountering new xpath.

Due to certain limitations (i.e., VisualStudio2005, .NET 2.0 Framework) not being able to use LINQ and many other features that can easily resolve this for me, this has become difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: What does "a new xpath" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such files, you should create a parser class based on [XmlTextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It is a pull parser implementation.

With the XmlTextReader, you have to read the whole XML node by node and extract the content required for your task. Here you will have to build by yourself the XPath query string by tracking nested elements and position count.

Comment: Definitely. I'd add that a `HashSet` is the obvious approach for storing those XPaths, since the querent wants to only store the unique values and this will automatically ignore duplicates. `HashSet` didn't come about until 3.5, but it's not hard to write one's own.